# How will the movement of cart create an effect on time period of oscillation of ball?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

In this question for finding the time period of bob I considered using the formula $T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$. It gives (d) option as one of the answer. My question is, will the movement of cart to keep the displacement of centre of mass zero, create an effect on time period of the bob or the formula will give the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: There is one point along the string that stays stationary relative to the ground. Since the cart moves, this point is no longer at the pivot (the top of the string). Where is it ?

Comment: Hint: Use conservation of momentum.  If there is only one right answer, it'll get you to it quickly

Comment: @napstablook Option (d) in the given problem is the period of the pendulum if the cart is *stationary* (and we take $g$ as $10$). The questioner is asking does the period change if the cart can move. My hint shows how you can see that the period of the pendulum *does* change if the truck can move - so it is no longer $\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate [gandalf61's correct answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/653087/305718):

When pendulum bob moves to one direction, the cart moves to the opposite direction. As a result of this, when observing with respect to the ground frame, the pendulum is oscillating about not the suspension point, but a point somewhere along the string.

[image]

That means, it is wrong if you use the length of the string for $l$ in the equation $T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac lg}$. For $l$ you need to calculate the distance from the bob to that stationary point.

> [image]

In fact, motion of the cart does affect the time period of the pendulum.

Then let's observe with respect to the cart's frame. There you can find a horizontal fictitious force acting on the pendulum due to acceleration of the cart (It is always changing because the cart also performs a simple harmonic motion). Since $g$ in the equation above represents *effective* gravitational acceleration, you can't simply plug in normal value for $g$ which is $9.8\text{m/s}$. This again implies that the period you get in this situation is not the time period when the suspension is at rest.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one correct answer, go with [C], which keeps the center of mass in place. For the purposes of calculation, one can put the mass of the cart at the top of the string.  Then the fixed center of mass would be 2/5 of the way down the string from the top, and the bob would be swinging  on an effective length of (3/5)(.3) m., giving a period of 0.8515 sec., and an amplitude of  (.18)sin($1.8^o$) = 0.00565 m.